# overlay html over flash?

Tags: html, flash, iframe, popup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Div Z-Index issue with Flash movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040887/div-z-index-issue-with-flash-movie)

Is  it possible to overlay a piece of html over a flash animation given this context:
-flash contents underneath is NOT clickable
-html will contain js link clicking which will open an iframe popup similar to: http://www.dynamic-tools.net/toolbox/popUp/

thanks!

Answer (score 13):

It is not standards-compliant, but try adding `wmode="transparent"` to the `embed` tag as follows:

```
<object> 
    <!-- ... -->
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/> 
    <embed src="flash_file.swf" wmode="transparent"></embed> 
    <!-- ... -->
</object>
```

With these parameters set, the flash movie *should* obey CSS z-index settings.

Answer (score 2):

Basically Mike Koval's answer will do the job, that is setting `wmode="transparent"`. All other HTML/CSS/JS things will remain the same from [your own link](http://www.dynamic-tools.net/toolbox/popUp/).

Full embedding code HTML version (by [swfObject's generator](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/list)) will be:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="800" height="600" id="myFlashContent">
        <param name="movie" value="path/to/flash.swf" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="path/to/flash.swf" width="800" height="600">
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <!--<![endif]-->
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
            </a>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

It will be always better to use [swfObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) in JS, something like:

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
params.wmode = "transparent";
var attributes = {};
swfobject.embedSWF("path/to/flash.swf", "id-of-the-div-the-flash-will-go", "800", "600", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```