# Div Z-Index issue with Flash movie

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, xhtml

I have two simple HTML divs one contains flash movie and another div contains simple text now my problem is that i have to put textual div onto the flash movie div what i am doing is setting the position of both divs to Absolute in CSS and setting the Z-Index of flash movie div to 1 and Z-Index of textual div to 2 but the text is coming behind the movie in every case but i have to put text onto movie, please help me in this regards so that my text may appear onto the flash movie. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a blog post that explains this issue

**[Flash content and z-index](http://joshuaink2006.johnoxton.co.uk/blog/82/flash-content-and-z-index)**

Use

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

From **[Flash OBJECT and EMBED tag attributes](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html)**

> **wmode**

Possible values: window, opaque, transparent. Sets the Window Mode property of the Flash movie for transparency, layering, and positioning in the browser.

```
* window - movie plays in its own rectangular window on a web page.
* opaque - the movie hides everything on the page behind it.
* transparent - the background of the HTML page shows through all 
  transparent portions of the movie, this may slow animation performance.
```

Comment: To clarify: if you're using `object`, insert it as `<object> ..other params.. <param name="wmode" value="transparent" /></object>`; if you're using `embed`, use `<embed ..other attrs.. wmode="transparent" ... />`

Comment: This link no longer exists: http://joshuaink2006.johnoxton.co.uk/blog/82/flash-content-and-z-index

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Flash getting in front of my fly-out menus. I tried two different techniques for element z-index re-ordering and they only worked for IE10.

This morning, I tried something that worked for all versions of IE, down to 7.

http://willstechcafe.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/overlays-vs-flash/