# how to overlay elements over flash?

Tags: html, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Div Z-Index issue with Flash movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040887/div-z-index-issue-with-flash-movie)

how can i overlay html elements over flash ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040887/div-z-index-issue-with-flash-movie/2040914#2040914) for another post.

Comment: can it work for youtube embed codes ?

Answer (score 1):

use iframe, same as IE6 fix for select(dropdown control) overlay