# External Flash Movie behind an HTML Overlay Div

Tags: html, css, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Div Z-Index issue with Flash movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040887/div-z-index-issue-with-flash-movie)

Okay, is there a way to have an external flash movie that I have iframed in from another server show up behind an overlay div? Currently when I open my overlay, the flash movie shows through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you either have the param `wmode` set to `transparent` or `opaque` - using the default setting (`window`) will place it above any other content (think: infinite z-index).

edit: if you are not able to embed the flash yourself, you may have issues - that param needs to be set.  Is it something that you can embed yourself just by moving the embed code to your site?

Comment: No, it's a map widget from esri.com, so I can't embed it myself unfortunately. You can see it here:

http://mapapps.esri.com/create-map/flash/Flex_m4e.html?width=600&height=350&xmin=-111.657699868081&ymin=33.372998864796855&xmax=-111.43454007804225&ymax=33.47328990632548&ptx=-12417257.275366565&pty=3951606.8507992644&dem=true&query=true&sb=true&demLyr=3&alpha=0.9&scale=144447.638572&cR=United%20States&fA=,%20

Comment: Unfortunately, you may need to have a workaround such as hiding the iframe (`visibility:hidden` versus `display:none`, to preserve document flow) if you want to display something above it, since you don't have control over the `wmode`.

Comment: That's actually a good idea. I think I will try that, thanks!