# Flash overlay click traversal

Tags: html, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Div Z-Index issue with Flash movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040887/div-z-index-issue-with-flash-movie)

It's almost christmas, and one of my colleague has a client with very particular (and, let's say it, ridiculous) needs : he has to put a giant flash overlay on a website with <strike>falling snowflakes</strike>  rose petals (!) in it, but the user must still be able to click on the html elements behind it.

Is that event possible and if yes, how?

EDIT: My colleague doesn't even know whether this is about snowflakes or not.

SECOND UPDATE: I just saw what it looks like, and it seems very hard to do: the petals are different from each other, and follow a complex trajectory. I thought of putting the flash in background, but there are some divs that must be behind the petals (that are fully opaque).

Comment: Why in flash? You could do it in JS faster and easier. (but yes, it's possible in flash... but a pain to put it in the background, changing a lot of css).

Comment: @Chouchenos : thanks for this comment, I think we'll try to talk the client into using javascript...

Comment: After your edit, I'll say _it depends_ on the animation he wants. Falling snowflakes are easy to do in JS, _animated snowmen throwing snowballs_ are something else ;)

Comment: @Chouchenos : I'll try to get some more details, it really is a bit hazy for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client expressed his opinion on what he considers would look best. In the end it's upto you to actually impress him.

Consider changing the header with flash - (snowmen throwing balls or other stuff....) with a look of having integrated it with the HTML background itself.

Add CSS overlays of falling roses (valentine??) or slowflakes & animate using javascript.

[Falling snow with Jquery.](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/falling-snow)    >>>>>  [Demo.](http://demos.9lessons.info/happyxmas.html)

[Creating Falling snow in Javascript.](http://www.hypergurl.com/snowmaker.html)

---

Of course creating a giant flash overlay is very much possible & also there are methods to access the HTML elements behind.

But why put it on top, work with flash transparency & ultimately reach for the html elements behind.... when you can simply use it as a background & keep the html elements on top.

---

Edit:
Can't you add what you need behind the flash to the flash movie itself....say in another layer? Try separating user Interaction & animation. Let all the graphic part be handled by flash While the html elements on top.

Can't help much, without a bit of example.

Comment: Interesting, detailed answer. I updated my post, so you can see that we are in the worst case.

Comment: I saw that, but as I said, the flash has to be in the foreground: some of the petals must hide html elements.