# Generate or parse HTML into SWF

Tags: php, html-parsing, flash, generator

Hello I need an option or approach to "convert" HTML to SWF. I have tested ming extension for PHP, but it does not allow me to pass directly HTML and parse it into SWF.

Currently I work in PHP, but any other solution that requires other platform/language is not a problem for me, if it works - node.js, ruby, python, etc.

Also, is there a way to build such SWF from Flash and put inside some WebView, that can display the HTML directly and what is the chance for that to have high percent of similarity between HTML and SWF preview (to look the same way as HTML in browser)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "convert" HTML into Flash without loosing functionality and styles.

HTML and JS are executed by browser, and Flash (action script) run by Flash Player, which are really different engines.

Flash do not have full HTML-parsing support.

I guess that you actually want to have a web page (php used as a backend, or just static page) shown in Flash-scene.
You can try something like this: http://activeden.net/item/flash-popup-as3/full_screen_preview/34326

You can also try overlaying HTML over flash, like here: [overlay html over flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567420/overlay-html-over-flash)

But i suggest the opposite, the standard way:
Flash embedded into HTML or no flash at all.