# IE11 Issue: When moving an IFrame with Flash in it, some background leaks through

Tags: javascript, css, flash, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a web page with roughly the following structure:

```
<div class="row">
  menu
</div>
<div class="row">
  optional content
</div>
<div class="row">
   <iframe src="(some flash application)"></iframe>
</div>
```

...wheere `.row` is set to `width: 100%;`

After a click on some part of the menu, the optional content div disappears / reappiers via JavaScript.

In IE11, when the optional content gets hidden, it seems to actually still exist somehow below the flash content, and parts of it leak through the flash. Sometimes it looks as if the hidden div got doubled, and one part is now where the flash content should be.

It all works fine in FF & Chrome.

When the user scrolls up and down a bit, the leakage disappears and the flash is displayed as it should.

`Z-Index` didn't change anything.

Currently, I'm wiggling the window a bit via JavaScript `window.scrollBy(0,1)`. That fixes it in about 80% of all cases, but not always. (Plus it's decidedly ugly of course.)

Any hints as to what causes that behaviour, and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answered by [overlay html over flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567420/overlay-html-over-flash):

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

does the trick.